# Using tools of complex analysis the distribution of zeroes of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Consider a monic polynomial $p(z)= z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdot + a_1 z + a_0.$ prove all zeros of p(z) lie the open disk centered at z=0 with the radius $R= \sqrt {1 + |a_{n-1}|^2+\cdot +|a_1|^2+|a_0|^2}.$

I try to use the Augumnet theorem , use limit to prove the roots lying around the circle ,failed… please help me if you like to .THX

Answer (score 3):

No complex analysis tools are required. It suffices to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the summation of a geometric progression.

As $R\ge 1$ it suffices to consider  $|z|>1.$ Assume $$z^n=-a_{n-1}z^{n-1}-\ldots -a_1z-a_0$$ Then
$$1=-a_{n-1}z^{-1}-\ldots -a_1z^{n-1}-a_0z^{-n}$$ By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get $$1\le (|a_{n-1}|^2+\ldots +|a_1|^2+|a_0|^2)\\ \times(|z|^{-2}+\ldots + 
 |z|^{-2(n-1)} +|z|^{-2n})\\ \le (|a_{n-1}|^2+\ldots +|a_1|^2+|a_0|^2){1\over |z|^2-1}$$ Hence $$
|z|^2\le 1+|a_0|^2+|a_1|^2+\ldots +|a_{n-1}|^2=R^2$$

Comment: Thx for sharing. I still confused with the case |z|<=1. How about it

Comment: Bingon($—$), I understand. Thx sincerely.